# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... @next/react-dev-overlay

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, next.js, webview

nextjs site is blank screen on android < 7 in webview

```
  "next": "^13.4.2"

client.js?4d30:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js (main.js?ts=1683969678639:297)
    at Object.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:800)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:455)
    at eval (hot-dev-client.js?1600:38)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js (main.js?ts=1683969678639:363)
    at Object.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:800)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1683969678639:455)
    at eval (webpack-hot-middleware-client.js?9ad2:12)
```

I'm using react-native-webview to show a next js site on android but its blank on android 7 and below that, I have tried other sites and they work fine.

Comment: I've been dealing with this exact issue for a few days now to no avail. Quite possibly be something to do with missing some polyfills, but I've not figured it out yet

Comment: I assume it's pointing at the `...` <spread operator>

Comment: Compiling to a lower JS target via a custom `.babelrc` gets rid of the spread spread operator issue, but introduces `"Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined", source: webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1058)`